# How to handle permissions to API in nodejs with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-structures, authorization

**Description of the situation**

I have an API for sharing inventory between businesses and e-commerce sites.

The businesses uploads their inventory and the sites can pull it to present it.

Each business have a list of permitted sites (IPs) in this form `businessCode:[IP1,IP2,IP3]`

The IPs are whitelisted in the server's firewall, but I still need a way to permit per business ( IP1 can read from businesss1 but not from business2 ).

**My stack**

nodejs, express, mongoDB

**My thoughts**

I thought about two possible options for this:

1. Each business will be a document in the permission collection in this form:

```
{
    bizCode: '1234', 
    permittedIps: [IP1, IP2, ...]
}
```

2. There will be only one document in the permission collection and it will be an object map of business to permittedIps:

```
{
   '1234': [IP1,IP2,...],
   '5555': [IP1, IP3,...],
   '1100': [IP2, IP4,...]
}
```

**My questions**

What is the right way of saving this data in mongoDB?
Is there a third option you can think of?

Comment: There is no right way, both sound fine and have pros and cons. I would suggest using the second option only if you are loading those permissions once initially (and maybe update with a interval) if you wanna check the permission for each request options 1 would mean that less data is sent between server and db.

Comment: thank you @mmoehrlein
So it seems that option 1 is the way for me